# Inbox Actions for Train Reservations

Tags: google-schemas

I want to use the schema that is listed here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/flight-reservation but for train reservations. Is that possible?

We have reservationNumbers, and rider information

But we don't issue train numbers or in schema "flightNumber", we also don't have a iataCode for the "airline", departurestation or arrival station, but we do have our own three letter codes that we use. Can I put alternate information in the fields, or do they have to exist in some sort of master database?

Thanks!

Kirk

Comment: Did you check the [TrainTrip](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/TrainTrip) and [TrainReservation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/TrainReservation) for Google Email Markup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible I have to do it recently they have a different type for a train reservation you can find the schema documentation for the type `TrainReservation` here https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/TrainReservation